# Solution to simple student probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics

1) At a certain university, 57% of students are female, 7% are enrolled in the Computer Science course and 6% are female and are studying Computer Science.

**a) Calculate the probability that a student chosen at random at the university is a female, given that she studies Computer Science.**

**b) Calculate the probability that a student chosen at random at the University is enrolled at the Computer Science course, given that the student is a female.**

*I've used the Bayes Theorem here but couldn't get the right answer*

Comment: Can you show work?

Comment: This is what I've done (and it's wrong)
A: Computer Science course
B: female gender

P(B|A) = [P(A|B)xP(B)]/P(A)
P(B|A) = (0.06x0.57)/0.07
P(B|A) = 0.488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant really comment, but I think I dont understand the given statistics here.
There is a university with 57% female students, 6% of the female students study computer science and 7% of all students study computer science?

In that case:

A: Calculate the probability that a random Computer Science student is a female.
Then you have to calculate the female computer science portion of the university: 0.57 * 0.06 = 0.0342 (3.42%).
Then you divide that by the 0.07: 0.0342 / 0.07 = ~0.48857 (48.9%)
I guess...

B: Calculate the probability that a random female student is studying computer science.
Isnt this just that 6%?

Comment: You understood it right, but the answers are

a. 0.857
b. 0.105

I'm not quite sure if that helps you to discover where we did it wrong.

Comment: a. sounds like 6% / 7%.